# Another example where I don't know if 欲しい or 欲しがる is right

Tags: word-choice, grammar

> 私の祖母は私が欲しい以上のものをくれた
>
> 私の祖母は私が欲しがる以上のものをくれた

I want the meaning to be "my grandmother gave me more then I wanted." Is the second sentence right and the first sentence wrong?

I learned 欲しがる for the third person, but I found the second example as a first person example. Which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generalization that がる is used only for third person is wrong. Both of your examples are grammatical, but only the first one means what you want.

> 私の祖母は私が欲しい以上のものをくれた
>
>  'My grandmother gave me more than what I wanted.'
>
> 私の祖母は私が欲しがる以上のものをくれた
>
>  'My grandmother gave me more than what I expressed that I wanted.'

Comment: +1 for squashing a common misconception, and for an exceptionally compact and elegant rendering of the difference in meanings.

Comment: thank you for your answer sawa. Your translation of the 2nd example i gave, however, is awkward in english-so I am wondering if the original sentence is awkward as well in japanese? Or could one translate it as "my grandmother gave me more than I told her I wanted" ( i know the 'told her' would be a very loose translation). Any further elaboration on the がる ending would be appreciated; as the answer to the other related question on this forum seems limited.